# BotFramework Emulator Refresh access token failed with status code: 500

Tags: botframework

Following the article https://blog.botframework.com/2017/06/19/Load-Testing-A-Bot/ to test a bot.
Im trying to get an accessToken, but Im getting a 500. The same is happening if I run the Emulator from code. The downloaded emulator works fine.

```
{
  "error": "server_error",
  "error_description": "AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials.\r\nTrace ID: 06f655dd-dc88-49ec-a429-1c86fc1a1b00\r\nCorrelation ID: 070d67cc-361f-45ad-a0bb-d07d5d1e73f4\r\nTimestamp: 2017-07-31 00:54:46Z",
  "error_codes": [
    70002
  ],
  "timestamp": "2017-07-31 00:54:46Z",
  "trace_id": "06f655dd-dc88-49ec-a429-1c86fc1a1b00",
  "correlation_id": "070d67cc-361f-45ad-a0bb-d07d5d1e73f4"
}
```

The process to get the access token is to post to https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token with

```
x-www-form-urlencoded values:
grant_type=client_credentials
client_id= <YOUR MSA APP ID>
client_secret = <YOUR MSA APP SECRET>
scope = <YOUR MSA APP ID>/.default
```

Note: a locally built version of the Emulator, with a fresh clone, also has the same issue, while the downloaded version connects correctly

Comment: Add how you are trying to get the accessToken please (process/code)

Comment: @NicolasR answered in my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest master on Emulator is breaking the access token request. You need to checkout the commit 4923221 to make it work.

To get the access token directly with a post request: the post url is https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token , and the scope is https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
The rest should be as specified previously